# Comparing between dataframes to find numbers +/- 1 of the observation in the same position in both dataframes

Tags: r

I have two dataframes at time point 1 and time point 2. Each Dataframe has a column "midpoint" and i want to compare the midpoint in dataframe 2 (time point 2) to the midpoint dataframe 1 (time point 1) such that if it is within +/- 1, a unique "id" is assigned in a column called "id" for each comparison that returns TRUE under the above parameters. If its false, then the id should be blank or 0. Ive been playing around with the ifelse() function with little success so far. Ive been trying to create a function so that the dataframe time point n, compares to the previous time point (n-1).

I will eventually use the purrr package to loop it for every timepoint (total of 130ish), for some context behind why im doing this.

Ignore the maximum and minimum column, these are relevant for something different, appreciate any help possible!

Dataframe 1 (time point 1)

```
structure(list(Object = c(2666L, 2668L, 2671L, 2674L, 2676L, 
2677L, 2678L, 2679L, 2680L, 2682L, 2683L, 2684L, 2685L, 2686L, 
2687L, 2689L, 2692L, 2693L, 2694L, 2695L, 2696L), minimum = c(4L, 
39L, 147L, 224L, 419L, 531L, 595L, 641L, 669L, 723L, 810L, 836L, 
907L, 978L, 1061L, 1129L, 1290L, 1519L, 1749L, 1843L, 1897L), 
    maximum = c(22L, 85L, 173L, 242L, 449L, 587L, 627L, 655L, 
    702L, 740L, 828L, 890L, 923L, 1024L, 1086L, 1144L, 1302L, 
    1544L, 1780L, 1870L, 1925L), midpoint = c(13, 62, 160, 233, 
    434, 559, 611, 648, 685.5, 731.5, 819, 863, 915, 1001, 1073.5, 
    1136.5, 1296, 1531.5, 1764.5, 1856.5, 1911)), row.names = c(NA, 
-21L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Dataframe 2 (time point 2)

```
structure(list(Object = c(2645L, 2646L, 2650L, 2652L, 2655L, 
2656L, 2657L, 2658L, 2659L, 2661L, 2662L, 2663L, 2664L, 2665L, 
2667L, 2670L, 2675L, 2681L, 2688L, 2690L, 2691L), minimum = c(4L, 
40L, 147L, 224L, 415L, 532L, 595L, 641L, 670L, 722L, 811L, 835L, 
907L, 978L, 1061L, 1128L, 1289L, 1520L, 1748L, 1843L, 1897L), 
    maximum = c(22L, 85L, 173L, 242L, 445L, 588L, 627L, 655L, 
    702L, 739L, 828L, 891L, 923L, 1022L, 1085L, 1143L, 1302L, 
    1544L, 1779L, 1870L, 1925L), midpoint = c(13, 62.5, 160, 
    233, 430, 560, 611, 648, 686, 730.5, 819.5, 863, 915, 1000, 
    1073, 1135.5, 1295.5, 1532, 1763.5, 1856.5, 1911)), row.names = c(NA, 
-21L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Expected output:

```
object minimum maximum midpoint id
2645      4       22       13    1
2646     40       85      62.5   2
2650     147      173     260    3
```

So the output is an additional column to dataframe 2, with a unique ID for each instance where midpoint in observation 1 (in df2) is within +/- 1 to observation 1 (in df1). As i want to compare to the n-1th dataframe because it represents the previous timepoint.

Comment: Hi. Thank you for the reproducible examples. Can you also share your expected output based on the two data frames you shared?

Comment: I have applied the changes you requested

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can subset `df2`on those rows in which `df2$midpoint` is within the desired range of `df1$midpoint`, store that subsetted dataframe as a new dataframe and add an `id`column to it:

```
df2new <- df2[df2$midpoint >= df1$midpoint - 1 & df2$midpoint <= df2$midpoint + 1, ]
df2new$id <- 1:nrow(df2new)

df2new
# A tibble: 20 x 5
   Object minimum maximum midpoint    id
    <int>   <int>   <int>    <dbl> <int>
 1   2645       4      22     13       1
 2   2646      40      85     62.5     2
 3   2650     147     173    160       3
 4   2652     224     242    233       4
 5   2656     532     588    560       5
 6   2657     595     627    611       6
 7   2658     641     655    648       7
 8   2659     670     702    686       8
 9   2661     722     739    730.      9
10   2662     811     828    820.     10
11   2663     835     891    863      11
12   2664     907     923    915      12
13   2665     978    1022   1000      13
14   2667    1061    1085   1073      14
15   2670    1128    1143   1136.     15
16   2675    1289    1302   1296.     16
17   2681    1520    1544   1532      17
18   2688    1748    1779   1764.     18
19   2690    1843    1870   1856.     19
20   2691    1897    1925   1911      20
```

Alternatively, if you wanted to keep `df2`as it is but 'flag' those rows that fall into the desired range with `1`and those that don't with `0`, you could do this:

```
df2$id <-ifelse(df2$midpoint >= df1$midpoint - 1 & df2$midpoint <= df2$midpoint + 1, 1, 0)
df2
# A tibble: 21 x 5
   Object minimum maximum midpoint    id
    <int>   <int>   <int>    <dbl> <dbl>
 1   2645       4      22     13       1
 2   2646      40      85     62.5     1
 3   2650     147     173    160       1
 4   2652     224     242    233       1
 5   2655     415     445    430       0
 6   2656     532     588    560       1
 7   2657     595     627    611       1
 8   2658     641     655    648       1
 9   2659     670     702    686       1
10   2661     722     739    730.      1
# … with 11 more rows
```

... and if you wnted to have a continuous range of `id` values that still marks the row outside the range (as it will just be a repetition of the previous `id`), then use `cumsum` on `id`:

```
df2$id2 <- cumsum(df2$id)
df2$id2[df2$id < 1] <- 0   # keep the `id` value `0`:
```

to obtain this:

```
df2
# A tibble: 21 x 6
   Object minimum maximum midpoint    id   id2
    <int>   <int>   <int>    <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
 1   2645       4      22     13       1     1
 2   2646      40      85     62.5     1     2
 3   2650     147     173    160       1     3
 4   2652     224     242    233       1     4
 5   2655     415     445    430       0     0
 6   2656     532     588    560       1     5
 7   2657     595     627    611       1     6
 8   2658     641     655    648       1     7
 9   2659     670     702    686       1     8
10   2661     722     739    730.      1     9 
# … with 11 more rows
```

Comment: Hello, this is really useful - this new dataframe has 20 observation as opposed to 21 in the original dataframe. Is it possible to assign an id of 0 to the observation that doesnt fit the rule so that I have a note of which "objects" aren't within +/- 1. Many thanks

Comment: Hello this is 99.5% of what i want, and i really appreciate you taking the time to answer. Is there anyway to make it so each id is unique i.e 1,2,3,4,0,5,6,7 is how it should look for the first 7 observations. As the only issue with the ID2 is that is recognised both an object that follows the rule, and doesnt follow the rule as the same id.

Comment: Have updated the answer again. If helpful and if it answers your question please consider accepting and/or upvoting it.

Comment: Thanks so much, I have upvoted and accepted it as an answer.

Comment: Thanks for accepting the answer. You have not though upvoted it ;) (that would be the upward triangle...)

Comment: Hey, because i have below 15 reputation the upvote isnt publicly displayed however it is still noted according to prompt i recieved.

Comment: Hello, i know its been a while but i was wondering if there was a way to compare the midpoint observation in dataframe 2 with all the midpoint observations in dataframe 1; as ive just realised that some of the dataframes have different numbers if rows. Thanks!

Comment: I'm afraid I'm too far away from your scenario. Please post this as a new question!

Comment: That is understandable, thanks anyway :) This is the title of the new question: "Function that looks at a previous dataframe, compares each observation and assigns a unique id that follows a rule" if you can answer it great if not thanks for all your help anyway!

Answer (score 0):

Since you want to check the points one-by-one, then this is probably what you are looking for,

```
i1 <- cumsum(-1 <= (df2$midpoint - df1$midpoint) | 1 >= (df2$midpoint - df1$midpoint))
i1[ave(i1, i1, FUN = length) != 1] <- 0
i1
#[1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21
```

Comment: Hello, thanks for your answer. The second function is useful however, at position 4 it is being listed as 0 despite not changing in midpoint (its the same midpoint between both dfs) is there anyway to adjust this to include when the midpoint doesnt change.

Comment: I have attached a screen shot: https://gyazo.com/ecc9734b983df3b6ef62e76bcb87ef7f                                                     As you can see at position 5, it is greater than +/- 1 however is still be attributed a unique id (5), when it should be a 0?